# Recommandation for a reliable and comprehensive source on word stress rules in English

Tags: discussion, resources, pronunciation

I am looking for a reliable and comprehensive enough book or source on **word stress rules** in English.

I have searched the internet and found various interesting web pages, some not comprehensive enough, others with erroneous examples.

Your suggestions and recommandations will be welcome.

Comment: We only do resource requests on Meta.

Comment: Most good dictionaries show which syllable to stress with a tick mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erik Fudge's book *[English Word-Stress](https://www.google.com/books/edition/English_Word_Stress/bZTtCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)* (orig. 1984, republished 2015) provides a comprehensive overview of the conventions for word stress in English. There may be better resources since 1984, but I think he provides a volume useful for a non-expert as well as valuable for an expert. He breaks down typical patterns with examples, and he deals with phenomena like compound words, prefixes, and pairs of homonyms with different parts of speech.

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation. I have bought the book.